# python argparse optional positional argument with detectable switch

Tags: python, argparse

I would like to invoce my programm like `program -s <optional value>`. I would like to assign a default value, but would also like to be able to detect if the `-s` switch was given. 
What I have:

```
max_entries_shown = 10
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-s",
    nargs = '?',
    default = max_entries_shown)
args = parser.parse_args()
```

This gives me a value of 10 for `args.s` if I don't give `-s` on the command line, and `None` if I specify `-s` without a value. What I want is `args.s` equal to `None` if no switch is given, and `args.s` set to the default value with `-s` given, and `args.s` equal to `custom_value` if run as `program -s custom_value`. How can I achive this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `const` instead of `default`. Quote from argparse Python Docs about when to use [const](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#const):

> When add_argument() is called with option strings (like -f or --foo) and nargs='?'. This creates an optional argument that can be followed by zero or one command-line arguments. When parsing the command line, if the option string is encountered with no command-line argument following it, the value of const will be assumed instead. See the nargs description for examples.

Additionally, I added a `type=int` because I assumed that you want to treat the input as an int.

So, your code should be:

```
max_entries_shown = 10
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-s",
    nargs = '?',
    const = max_entries_shown,
    type=int)
args = parser.parse_args()
```

This code returns (with print args)

```
$ python parse.py
Namespace(s=None)
$ python parse.py -s
Namespace(s=10)
$ python parse.py -s 12
Namespace(s=12)
```