# Argparse value for optional positional argument

Tags: python, argparse

I am trying to create an argparse optional argument that may -OR- may not have an associated input value. I want the following behavior:
 1. argument not specified, value=None
 2. argument specified with a value, value=user_input
 3. argument specified without a value, value=derived from a positional value

The first 2 are easy. It's the third one I can't figure out. I found 2 posts that do something similar:
[python argparse optional positional argument with detectable switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17270629)
This one sets the default value to a constant for an optional argument without a value.
[Argparse optional positional arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480075)
This topic is close, but not quite what I need either (he derives the default value from a system call):
I want mine to be a determined from an positional value.

Simple example code I created:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('input')
parser.add_argument('-c', '--csv', nargs='?')
parser.add_argument('-p', '--pnf', nargs='?')
```

When I set the input and print:

```
args = parser.parse_args('my.h5 -c my_file.csv --pnf'.split())
print ('Input = %s' % args.input)
print ('CSV file = %s' % args.csv)
print ('PNF file = %s' % args.pnf)
```

I get:

```
Input = my.h5
CSV file = my_file.csv
PNF file = None
```

If I modify my input to:

```
args = parser.parse_args('my.h5 -c'.split())
```

The resulting output is:

```
Input = my.h5
CSV file = None
PNF file = None
```

When `Value = None`, I can't tell if the optional argument was not defined, or was defined but without a value. In the second case, I want to derive the CSV File name from the positional argument (in this example the derived name would be `my.csv`). I want to do the same when --pnf is defined (where default PNF would be `my.pnf` for above). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Use `const='foobar'` as described in the link. After parsing conditionally replace 'foobar' with `args.input`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I can't tell if the optional argument was not defined, or was defined but without a value

If you create your parser [like this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argument-default):

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(argument_default=argparse.SUPPRESS)
```

Now it is  possible to distinguish between the three cases.

- If `-c val` was passed, it will be present in `args` with value `"val"`.
- If `-c` was passed without value, it will be present in `args` with value `None`.
- If `-c` was omitted entirely, it won't be present in `args`.

The same goes for `-p`.

If you only want this suppression to apply for one option, rather than on the whole parser, that is possible too:

```
parser.add_argument('-c', '--csv', nargs='?', default=argparse.SUPPRESS)
```

Comment: Thanks, works like a champ (with a small change to get the arguments and values) I saw that in the python.org docs, but couldn't decipher how it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Making use of the `const` parameter:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('input')
parser.add_argument('-c', '--csv', nargs='?', const='foobar')
parser.add_argument('-p', '--pnf', nargs='?', const='foobar')

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)

if args.csv and args.csv=='foobar':
    args.csv = args.input

args.pnf = args.input if (args.pnf and args.pnf=='foobar') else args.pnf

print(args)
```

Your two sample inputs:

```
0933:~/mypy$ python3 stack53228663.py my.h5 -c my_file.csv --pnf
Namespace(csv='my_file.csv', input='my.h5', pnf='foobar')
Namespace(csv='my_file.csv', input='my.h5', pnf='my.h5')

0933:~/mypy$ python3 stack53228663.py my.h5 -c
Namespace(csv='foobar', input='my.h5', pnf=None)
Namespace(csv='my.h5', input='my.h5', pnf=None)
```

Comment: Thanks hpaulj, that's another approach. Not sure which is more "pythonic". Personally, I like `argparse.SUPPRESS` b/c it's more readable (to me).

Comment: You can also set this default in the `add_argument` command: `default=argparse.SUPPRESS`.  In my version, `default` is `None`.  And your 'const' is effectively `None`.  Which is easier to test for, a `None` value or a missing attribute or key?  Just as long as you are clear about the alternatives it really doesn't matter which you use.

Comment: "Which is easier: test a value or test for a missing key"?  
Yes, exactly, either way I'm writing some code to test and set the value.  :-)
In a perfect world, I'd like an action that combines action='store' and action='store_true'. When the optional argument is not entered, it's returned as 'False'. When it's entered without a value, it's returned as 'True'. And, when entered with a value, it's returned with that value -- or maybe returned as a tuple with: (argname, True/False, value).

Comment: That's easy - `nargs='?', default=False, const=True`.  `store_true` is just `store_const` with those default and const values (and `nargs=0`).

Comment: Yeah, I like that one. Didn't realize I could use `default=` and `const=` together. Good to know! Test logic is very clean and readable. You should post as an answer so I can +1. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For completeness (and future reference), I am posting the modified code required to get arguments when using `argument_default=argparse.SUPPRESS`. See below:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(argument_default=argparse.SUPPRESS)
parser.add_argument('input')
parser.add_argument('-c', '--csv', nargs='?')
parser.add_argument('-p', '--pnf', nargs='?')
args = parser.parse_args('my.h5 -c my_file --pnf'.split())
for d_key, d_val in vars(args).items() :
  print (d_key, d_val)
```

Results in this output:

```
input my.h5
csv my_file
pnf None
```

For the second set of inputs

```
args = parser.parse_args('my.h5 -c'.split())
print(vars(args))
for d_key, d_val in vars(args).items() :
  print (d_key, d_val)
```

Output looks like this:

```
input my.h5
csv None
```

Answer (score 0):

This shows the logic I implemented using `default=False, const=True`, based on earlier comments from @hpaulj.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('input')
parser.add_argument('-c', '--csv', nargs='?', default=False, const=True)
parser.add_argument('-p', '--pnf', nargs='?', default=False, const=True)
args = parser.parse_args('my.h5 -c'.split())
print(vars(args))
HDF5_FILE = args.input
if isinstance(args.csv, str) :
  CSV_FILE = args.csv
elif args.csv :
  CSV_FILE=HDF5_FILE[:-3] + '_v3_stress.csv'
else :
  CSV_FILE = ''
# repeat above logic for args.pnf
print ('input=', HDF5_FILE, ',  csv=', CSV_FILE, ' pnf=', PNF_FILE )
```

Resulting output looks like this:

```
{'input': 'my.h5', 'csv': True, 'pnf': False}
hdf5= my.h5 ,  csv= my_v3_stress.csv  pnf=
```

Modified 'parse_args()' and resulting output:

```
args = parser.parse_args('my.h5 -c my_file.csv -p'.split())
```

Gives:

```
{'input': 'my.h5', 'csv': 'my_file.csv', 'pnf': True}
hdf5= my.h5 ,  csv= my_file.csv  pnf= my_v3_stress.nrf
```

If I had a lot of variables to check, I would move the `if/elif/else` logic to a `def` that returns the desired value.